# Google login does not work with Arora

Tags: bug, status-declined, login

Using [Arora](http://code.google.com/p/arora/) 0.8 I'm unable to log in to any of the stackoverflow sites. Even though I'm logged in with Google ( confirmed by Gmail ), I don't appear logged in to SO (for example).

---

For context:

> Arora is a lightweight cross-platform web browser. It's free (as in free speech and free beer). Arora runs on Linux, embedded Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS X, Windows and any other platforms supported by the Qt toolkit.
>
> Arora uses the QtWebKit port of the fully standards-compliant WebKit layout engine. It features fast rendering, powerful JavaScript engine and supports Netscape plugins.

Comment: declining this because I don't think it's our bug

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE: RESOLVED**

There is a feature in Arora to disable "tracking cookies" which is turned on by default.
Generally this is a "Good Thing [TM]", but in the OpenID world it is actually desired.

To login with Arora you need to go into your preferences:

```
Menu > Edit > Preferences...

Privacy (Tab) > Cookies > Uncheck "Filter Tracking Cookies"
```

---

Original answer:

I too can not login via Arora... I get authenticated using (MyOpenID) and redirected to StackOverflow but I still appear as a guest user.

(Note: it works fine in Safari 4, and Chrome 2 on the same PC)

If I check out the headers coming back to StackOverflow from my OpenID provider (MyOpenID) I see the following:

(Using IE8 and Arora 0.8)

**Identical**

```
GET: /users/authenticate/?token=...
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: stackoverflow.com
```

**Different** (IE = Internet Explorer, AR = Arora)

```
IE: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
AR: Accept-Encoding: gzip

IE: Accept-Language: en-us
AR: {not sent}

IE: Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/x-silverlight, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*
AR: Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5


IE: Cookie:
            ASP.NET_SessionId=...
            _qca=...
            _qcb=...
            _utma=...
            _utmb=...
            _utmc=...
            _utmz=...
            openid_provider=myopenid
AR: Cookie:
            ASP.NET_SessionId=...
            _qca=...
            _qcb=...
            openid_provider=myopenid
```

The lack of the _utm(x) cookies makes me wonder... I checked in Firefox too and Firefox is getting the 4 _utm(a|b|c|z) cookies as well.

**Update**

There's an issue filed on the Arora bug tracking site (from July 2nd, 2009) that indicates issues logging into StackOverflow. ([Arora Issue 507](http://code.google.com/p/arora/issues/detail?id=507&can=1&q=stackoverflow.com&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars))... I'm "guessing" that the issue might be with Arora vs. StackOverflow.

Comment: I assume that's Windows, right? I'd like to disallow the _Oh it's Linux_ solutions.

Comment: yeah, this on on WinXP SP3. I can log into StackOverflow on all of the following browsers (yeah I'm a geeky web dev)... IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox 2, 3, 3.5, Chrome 1, 2, Opera 9.52, 9.64, Safari 3, 4.  I've even tried changing the Arora Cookie settings to "Allow cookies from all domains" (not just the ones I navigate to) but it didn't help.